# validate jar file : jar not loaded servlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jar

I know this question has many answers. But it is not solving my problem.

**ERROR:**

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\pathTo\wtpwebapps\WEB-INF\lib\mycustom.jar) - 
jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, sectoin 9.7.2. Offending class: 
javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

**THINGS THAT I UNDERSTOOD**

It's under wtpwebapps not webapps directory.

Java build path has my custom jar and it is present in the `wtpwebapps\web-inf\lib` directory also.

My customjar is a web application. Will it contain `servlet-api jar`? How do i check whether a jar contains a jar? I can check whether a class is present in a jar.

If it contains `servlet-api.jar`, is it causing the problem? How do i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the scope of the `servlet-api.jar` to `provided` in the maven config.

Comment: ApplicationOne is using my custom jar. You mean `pom.xml` of `ApplicationOne`

Comment: Yep, correct. The `servlet-api.jar` is present in the container and it conflicts with the one, coming in your jar.

Comment: But if i search for `servlet-api` in my `pom.xml`, the thing i found is it is excluded. `<dependency> some cdh artifacts - hbase <exclusion>servlet api is here</exclusion>....`

Comment: If this error occurs, that means you have a conflicting `servler-api.jar` *somewhere* in your classpath. I would suggest to double-check the dependencies that you load with the application to the container.

Comment: Hi, I found another thing. Two `servlet-api` jars are in `dependecy hierachy`. One is from `jetty server` and another is from `cdh hbase`.

Comment: That's exactly what I ment :) Moreover, have a look at the `lib` directory of your container :)

Comment: look for what? You mean look for `servlet api` jar? How do i remove one of these two? ``like `exclusions` ?

Comment: Yes, exclude those libs from the runtime, because this lib will be provided by container.

Comment: Another doubt. I need `cdh hbase` and `jetty` for some reasons. These two refers `servlet api` of diff versions. How do i exclude this `transitive dependency`? like `exclusions exlusions servletapi` under dependency tags of these??

Comment: Exclude inside dependency.

Comment: Hi,  I have excluded it. But didn't solve my problem